# DB2/400 TIMESTAMP field manipulation in .NET

Tags: .net, datetime, db2-400

I have a column in a DB2/400 table as TIMESTAMP type.

I am filtering like this:

```
select scmach,count(*) from f55br001 where sctrdj >='2013-08-30 00:00:00' group by scmach order by scmach
```

In a simple ASP.NET Web Pages app i am using it like this:

```
var lastUpdate = db.QuerySingle("select max(sccrdj) as LASTUPDATE from PRODDTA.F55BR001 where SCTRDJ >= '" + dateParam + "'");
    var maxDate = lastUpdate.LASTUPDATE;
```

and then:

```
<h3>
    Last update: @maxDate
</h3>
```

in the web page its being printed as:

```
2013-08-31-14.01.09.000000
```

I cant find any way to convert it in a proper datetime field.

GetType() says its a string when it comes from db and DateTime.Parse doesnt work either

EDIT:

The only way i found is using ParseExact. Is this the proper way?

```
string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.FFFFFF";
    var maxDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lastUpdate.LASTUPDATE,dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `var maxDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lastUpdate.LASTUPDATE,"yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.FFFFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`Yes it is a right way of conversion.

Comment: I believe my co-worker just went ahead and did a substring for each portion of the datetime and rebuilt it that way. Definitely not elegant, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is using `ParseExact`.

```
string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.FFFFFF";
var maxDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lastUpdate.LASTUPDATE,dateFormat, 
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```